# Replacing enter key with button

Tags: jquery

I have this chart generated when enter key is pressed. I want to use a simple button instead : http://www.cb-dev.tk/A/

Here is the init.js file :

```
$(function(){
    var input = $('.input'),
        bar = $('.bar'),
        bw = bar.width(),
        percent = bar.find('.percent'),
        ps =  percent.find('span'),
        name = 'rotate';

    input.on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            var t = $(this), val = t.val();
            if (val >=0 && val <= 1000){
                var w = 1000-val, pw = (bw*w)/1000,
                    pa = {
                        width: w/10+'%'
                    },
                    cw = (bw-pw)/2,
                    ca = {
                        left: cw
                    }
                ps.animate(pa);                 
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;
$('button.yourbutton').click(function(){
  input.trigger(e); // input is your $('.input')
});
```

By doing `input.trigger(e)` you're 'simulating' pressing enter key on that input. So basically you're calling that callback function on input keydown...

If you want another element to call that function, just bind something else instead of input i.e. `$('button').click(...)`

Answer (score 0):

just put all that code in the button click event , and get rid of the code for keypress that you have now

```
$('button.yourbutton').click(function(){
     var input = $('.input'),
     bar = $('.bar'),
     bw = bar.width(),
     percent = bar.find('.percent'),
     ps =  percent.find('span'),
     name = 'rotate';
     var t = input, val = t.val();
        if (val >=0 && val <= 1000){
            var w = 1000-val, pw = (bw*w)/1000,
                pa = {
                    width: w/10+'%'
                },
                cw = (bw-pw)/2,
                ca = {
                    left: cw
                }
            ps.animate(pa);                 
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function(e){
    var t = $('select'), val = t.val();
    if (val >=0 && val <= 1000){
        var w = 1000-val, pw = (bw*w)/1000,
            pa = {
                width: w/10+'%'
            },
            cw = (bw-pw)/2,
            ca = {
                left: cw
            }
        ps.animate(pa);                 
    }
});
```

So in that, you'll have to modify the selector for the button.  Also, on your page you were taking data from a single input.  You were able to use `$(this)` before to get that select element, but now you can't, since `this` is the button that is clicked.  So I changed the code to use `$('select')`, which you'll probably want to make more specific by adding an id to the select and using the id as the selector.